# Add custom fields to the cart line items in Craft Commerce 3

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, vue

I have a product variants with the custom field for the variant image.

In a cart overview I need to show an image of added line item (image should be of the added product variant if there are variants set for this product).

I have to do this with axios request, and I'm not using any twig templates; I'm using headless Craft with decoupled frontend on Nuxt.js.

How can I fetch one with the cart request? thank you in advance